Is there a Nvidia surround function or equivalent for Ubuntu?
I use my three 1920x1080p monitors as one 5760x1080p monitor when I do race sim at home. I have been using windows for the last 10 years but with Windows 10 EOL approaching I thought of giving Ubuntu another go. I mainly play games on my computer, mostly low requirement stuff except for the sim racing games so most should be fine via wine or similar. But the Nvidia surround is the biggest thing holding me back at the moment.

Have you checked the Nvidia web site for info?

@David from there forums it seems a bit dead that's why the question, if there's an alternative to make 3 monitors act like one. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-surround-span-across-3-monitors/236740/4

I've read about it here. It boils down to create your own xconf profile. Won't work with wayland.

Have you tried using gamescope?
After installing gamescope, you can launch your game like this gamescope --xwayland-count 1 -w 5760 -h 1080 -- <original command to run game>.
